# What are the labels for Direct and Cloud API nomenclature?

Tags: smart-home

Smart thermostat connect to the cloud to enable remote control from the internet.  If the cloud server fails for technical or economic reasons then remote control stops.

Remote control via direct queries / commands, between the controller and the remote device via an API is known as ?????.   In contrast, remote control through a cloud intermediary is labeled  ????

I am seeking to find two labels: one for direct control APIs presented by the remote device, versus APIs presented by a cloud intermediatiary

Comment: What is the exact question?

Comment: Hopefully the updates clarify.  I am seeking to find two labels: one for direct control APIs presented by the remote device, versus APIs presented by a cloud intermediatiary.  Any assistance (editing) of the question is welcomed to clarify the question